# Open SharePoint app in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I'm developing a SharePoint Hosted app and want to access its contents from SharePoint Designer so I can edit the pages and javascript files without having to deploy the app for every change I made to those files.

I'm receiving the following message:

[image: SPD message]

Is that even possible or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just run into this issue. It's not about settings in the Host-SiteCollection, I think its probably related to some kind of permissions into the App.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. Microsoft has restricted access to App Webs using SharePoint Designer.

Comment: @RobWindsor .is possible to view the app code which is installed from SharePoint store ?.I have installed one app but i don't have idea to move this into another SP server. please suggest any idea.

Comment: @GokulPgp Yes you can see the code for a SharePoint-hosted App. You just need to navigate to the SharePoint site that was created when the app was installed (i.e. the App Web). The JavaScript code that implements the app will be contained in this site.